# How to set 'enter' to 'rename' file in windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a way to set the 'enter' key to 'rename' files in 'file explorer'? Particularly for windows 10, if it matters.
["set enter to rename"]

Comment: I presume this is to emulate the Mac behaviour. idk of anything directly comparable in Windows, F2 is the Win default, but you don't really want to remap that or you'll lose your main Enter key functionality.

Comment: Thanks, and yes it is to emulate osx behavior. I know of F2, but I find it inconvenient due to muscle memory and also its physical location. I know of software like ShapKeys, but I agree, I don't want to remap the enter button globally. I only wish to alter it's function in windows proprietary file explorer (hence the desktop too). It would be awesome if it was an app for that or something to alter in the registry maybe?

Comment: Sharpkeys is the best remap utility out there. Also, no, you don't want to remap the Enter key, even if you can. Keys cannot be remapped for a single application, and File Explorer is an integral part of Windows and it pops up in ways and places that you wouldn't expect.